# Cannot resolve method 'setAllowNewEmailAccounts(boolean)'

Tags: google-signin

```
AuthUI.getInstance()
      .createSignInIntentBuilder()
      .setAllowNewEmailAccounts(true)
      .build(), LOGIN_PERMISSION
```

Answer (score 0):

To kick off the FirebaseUI sign in flow, create a sign in intent with your preferred sign-in methods:
Insted of using .setAllowNewEmailAcounts(true) used .setAvailableProviders(providers) and declare the provider Array before create method like this

```
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build());
```

And Then within create method used startActivityForResult Like This

```
           startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build(),
            PER_LOGIN);
```

I hope this will solve your problem